# paintEvent() for a specific Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

This example draws an ellipse in the main window. I would like to draw the ellipse in the secondary window as soon as I click the pushbutton in the main window. This, however, without having to create another class. I tried but I can't.

Another question: Is it possible to insert a geometric figure in a Box Layout?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QBrush,QPen
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        title = "Main Window";left=100;top=100;width=1200;height=800
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)
        self.Create_Button()
        self.show()

    def Create_Button(self):
        button = QPushButton("Click", self)
        button.setGeometry(30,100,200,80)
        button.clicked.connect(self.SecondWin)

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QtCore.Qt.red,6,QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45,171,200),QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawEllipse(550,150,300,600)

    def SecondWin(self,event):
        mydialog = QDialog(self)
        mydialog.setWindowTitle("Second Window")
        mydialog.setGeometry(400,200,600,300)
        mydialog.show()


    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: What button do you mean? I do not see any buttons in the secondary window. What *Box Layout* do you mean?

Comment: I think Nepura wants to draw the same ellipseItem of the mainwindow on the mydialog.And Box Layout is only in the Nepura's head.We can't understand it and where it is.right?

Comment: I mean the QPushButton Click on the main window. The other question is for a hypothetical Box Layout.

Comment: And you don't want to create subclass of the second window for drawing the same ellipseitem.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I want to click the button in the main window and view the drawing in the secondary window, without creating other classes.

Comment: @Nepura  it is impossible or at least not recommended, you have to subclassify.

Comment: @Nepura Why do not you want to inherit ?, Also how to point out you have a bad English so I recommend you take your time to post your question, in addition to editing your current publication that is not clear at all.

Comment: It was simply to understand if I could make a code reduced to the bone, thanks eyllanesc.

Comment: @Nepura I recommend not to try to reduce without clear reasons, the inheritance is a good practice that just serves to reduce code because when it is inherited from another class is not written much of the code of the base class.

Comment: If you don't want to subclass `QMainWindow` and `QDialog`, you can create a new class which drawing an ellipse. Then, create two instances (one as *central widget* and one as child of your dialog).